# Connect to MSSQL from QGIS on Mac

Tags: qgis, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I tried to connect to MSSQL from QGIS and I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

I install MSSQL on my Mac with Docker and try to connect QGIS with localhost(host=localhost) and left the DSN empty, also inserted USER&PASS.

I tried to insert the IP instead, even mentioning the port (1433), nothing helped.

Did anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

[image: ...]

Comment: use the MAC MSSQL driver  for OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), macOS 10.12 (Sierra), and macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) > https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 (install via curl) >  https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release

Comment: @Mapperz,thanks for your time.... I tried to do it and it didn't work. I also tried to uninstall MSSQL and install again and then install the ODBC using brew but it didn't help as well.
I don't know if it is important but when I installed the 'msodbcsql17' & 'mssql-tools' the "-no--sandbox" option didn't worked so I installed it with out this option. 
do you have any more ideas?

Comment: cross-ref stack exchange > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120781/error-installing-mssql-tools-with-brew-on-mac-os/44120782

Comment: @Mapperz, already tried it, still getting the same error while try to connect the server to QGIS. I checked the server and it's working and I can query the tables.

Comment: I think this same issue applies to Linux (Ubuntu, Mint for sure)...